# How to create record Type Selector that changes the way your form looks depends of the record type selected in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, record-type, form

As you can see in the picture ,I want to be able to select a record type then the form that appears will depend on the record type selected , I will have two record types

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: i tried this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info   but i cant get anywhere with it

Comment: `uiObjectInfoApi` would return record type list, you can display them on the UI right?#

Comment: Im a begineer can you please explain it more thanks

Comment: I will try it thank u

Comment: tried it  ; Im just getting a selector (picklist) and not redirecting me anywhere